# Maximizing the window doesn't work through the bamboo agent service

Tags: bamboo

I am using the below code to maximize the browser window.

```
  obj =  Win32API.new("user32.dll", "FindWindow", ['P','P'], 'i')
  hwnd = obj.call(classname, winname)

  wndConsole = Win32API.new( "user32.dll" , "ShowWindow" , ['i' , 'i'] , 'i' )
  result = wndConsole.call( hwnd , 3 )
```

They work fine if I launch bamboo through command line.
But they doesn't work if I launch bamboo through the service.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what i ran into, but if Bamboo is running as a service in which you've given it GUI access, then the maximum resolution available is 800x600.